# RadContextMenu has extra space, doesn't auto-close

Tags: wpf, telerik, contextmenu

I'm doing some introductory work in WPF (my experience is almost exclusively web development) and I'm a bit stuck on what appears to be a styling issue with a RadContextMenu.

The XAML for the menu is simple enough:

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
    <telerik:RadContextMenu EventName="Click" ItemsSource="{Binding NewEntityMenuItems}" StaysOpen="False">
        <telerik:RadContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding MenuItemClickedCommand}" StaysOpenOnClick="False"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
</telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
```

The runtime result ends up like this:

[image]

As you can see, when hovering over the item there are two highlighted regions, one within the other.  If I click the "outer region" for the menu item, the command isn't invoked but the menu does disappear.  If I click the "inner region" (the one with the text), the command *is* invoked but the menu does *not* disappear.

Why are there separate regions?  Can I have just a single region which takes up the width of the menu?  And which also closes the menu when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Use ItemContainerStyle:

```
<n:RadContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}">
    <n:RadContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="n:RadMenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSeparator" Value="{Binding IsSeparator}" />
        </Style>
    </n:RadContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</n:RadContextMenu>
```